# How to style Polymer dropdown menu arrow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, polymer

New to Polymer, and the docs seem a little 'light' on examples. I'm trying to style a dropdown menu so everything is white on a blueish background. Most things (tabs, toast, etc.) are working, but the dropdown-menu stubbornly refuses to show the little 'arrow' button in anything other than murky grey.

[Example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zumuqobazu/1/edit?html,output)

The styling code is:

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;

    /* Main vars */
    --ki-teal: #4790A8;
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: #fff;
    --paper-tab-ink: #fff;

    /* Toolbar colours */
    paper-toolbar.ki {
      --paper-toolbar-background: var(--ki-teal);
    }

    /* Project select dropmenu colours */
    paper-dropdown-menu-light.ki {
      --paper-dropdown-menu-color: #fff;
      --paper-dropdown-menu-focus-color: #fff;
      --paper-dropdown-menu-button: {
        color: #fff;
      }
      --paper-input-container-color: var(--ki-teal);
      --paper-input-container-focus-color: #fff;
      --paper-dropdown-menu-input: {
        border-bottom: none;
      };
    }

    /* Notifications */
    #toastSave {
      --paper-toast-background-color: var(--ki-teal);
      --paper-toast-color: white;
    }

  }
</style>
```

But the `--paper-dropdown-menu-button` doesn't seem to have any effect, or I'm not using it right. Any guidance appreciated.

In addition, you'll see (at least on Chrome/Windows) that the underline bar when the dropdown has focus is not aligned properly with the active tab bar. I guess that's just a Polymer CSS glitch which will get worked out eventually, unless it's something I need to take care of in the `<style>` section as well?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--iron-icon-fill-color` in your `paper-dropdown-menu` class if you want have other `iron-icons` also which you don't want to style, else you can style use it in `host` if you want.

Another way of doing it will be giving color to mixin `--paper-dropdown-menu-icon`. As per `paper-dropdown-menu` [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu) it is

> A mixin that is applied to the internal icon

Lastly, if you look at the [code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/master/paper-dropdown-menu-light.html#L247) of `paper-dropdown-menu-light` you'll notice that icons have default value as `--disabled-text-color`. So, if  you change this value that should do the trick for you. I'll recommend not to use this method as this is a default variable for material design theme and Polymer has used this as default value at lot of places. So, unless to know what you are doing avoid this method.

In Polymer if an element is using some other element internally you can always refer the style guide of internal element and use it directly. Like here we are using `iron-icons` styles to style the icon which is inside `paper-dropdown-menu`

I don't think Polymer has directly mentioned this in their styling guide but you can find this detail written at the end of `styling` details of [paper-dropdown-menu](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu) and generalise it

> You can also use any of the paper-input-container and paper-menu-button style mixins and custom properties to style the internal input and menu button respectively.

Comment: Fab - many thanks. For extra credit, where should I have looked in the docs for this? I followed paper-dropdown-menu, which references paper-menu-button, but I didn't see anything in there which refers to iron-icons. And paper-dropdown-menu mentions the --paper-dropdown-menu-button mixin which is applied to the internal menu button, but how? Could it be used to achieve the same effect without referencing iron-icons?

Comment: Yeah - I tried using the paper-menu-button mixin, but I couldn't make any change to the icon - only your suggestion to use iron-icon worked. Is there a 'better' way using paper-menu-button? I put my best guess in this updated JSBin, but it doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/zitaqesisa/edit?html,output

Comment: i've added two more ways of achieving what you want to. Anyways, i don't think there is anything wrong with changing `--iron-icon-fill-color` neither do i feel other methods are better or worse then it.